# PHP use namespace with soap

Tags: php, soap, namespaces

I am writing a php code.

```
<?php 

    namespace includeV5{

         $soapServer=new SoapServer(null,array("uri"=>"soapT.php"));

     }      
 ?>
```

The Above Code will display the error message:*Fatal error: Class 'includeV5\SoapServer' not found*.

If I don't use the namespace, it will execute successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside namespace you must provide absolute namespace path. This code will work both in namespace or not:

```
$soapServer = new \SoapServer(null,array("uri"=>"soapT.php"));
```